# In Postman how to mock a post API call to return reponses based on the request body?

Tags: postman

I'm trying to leverage Postman's mock server feature to mock an API that my application calls.
This is a Post request. I have gone through the documentation and as advised I have saved the responses as examples.

When I try hit the mock URL I get the postman error response
[image]

Here is my setup -
My Collection with saved examples
[image]
MY mock server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After going through your query, I can see that you're trying to match an example based on the body passed with the request.

To match an example based on the request body, you can leverage the body matching feature of mock servers by:

- Enabling the body matching feature from the mock edit page (Reference: https://learning.postman.com/docs/designing-and-developing-your-api/mocking-data/setting-up-mock/#matching-request-body-and-headers).

**OR**

- Passing an additional `x-mock-match-request-body` header with value as `true` along with your mock request to get the desired results.

You can find more information on how to use body matching feature with mock servers here: https://learning.postman.com/docs/designing-and-developing-your-api/mocking-data/matching-algorithm/#6-check-for-header-and-body-matching.

Do let me know if this doesn't solve your issue. In that case, it would be helpful if you can share the mock request that you're sending to get the response.

Comment: Thank you very much. I did add the required header x-mock-match-request-body.